# Why do I always get performance errors in Codility?

Tags: c++

I always seem to get timeout errors for almost every program that I do although it seems to be syntactically correct. For example this is my code for GenomicRangeQuery:

```cpp
vector<int> solution(string &S, vector<int> &P, vector<int> &Q) {

    int i, n, j, B;
    int min;
    n=P.size();
    vector<int> C;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        min=4;
        for(j=P[i]; j<=Q[i]; j++)
        {
            switch(S[j])
            {
                case 'A':
                         B=1;
                         break;
                case 'C':
                         B=2;
                         break;
                case 'G':
                         B=3;
                         break;
                case 'T':
                         B=4;
                         break;
            }
            if(B<min)
            {
                min=B;
            }
        }
        C.push_back(min);

    }
    return C;
}
```

Syntactically it is correct but all three performance cases throw timeout errors.

Comment: Timeout errors indicate that program is too slow so you should figure out how to make it faster.

Answer (score 1):

There are requirements per task regarding the performance; in most cases it's about the time-complexity. The aforementioned `GenomicRangeQuery` doesn't impose such hard limitations, but it requires an efficient solution.

To me the first possible optimization of your solution would be to early exit on the first occurance of `A` as it means that minimal impact factor for the whole sequence will for sure be `1`. Imagine a sequence : ATTT[....]T (1 A and 99,999 times T). You can exit after first `A` and still the minimal impact is `1`.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! I tried that but that didn't seem to have an effect on the timeout errors. Getting rid of the nested for loops did the trick. Thanks though!